# ng-repeat not showing array generated from objects received from the web service response in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic v1 app where it gets a response from the server in json format and puts the data inside an array.

I'm trying to display this array elements inside an HTML div as a checkbox list that user can select the items by checking the checkbox. My problem is that array is not being displayed in the HTML page can anyone please help me on this?

This is my HTML Code

```
<div id="btnid" class="list itemsDiv">
  <ion-list class="bg" ng-repeat="item in results">
    <ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in results">
      {{ item.ItemName }}
    </ion-checkbox>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

And here is my Angular Code:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://Website/Webform?id=1',
    method: "GET"
  })
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.temp = response.data;
      $scope.results = response.data.Cargo;
      console.log($scope.results);
      $scope.result = [];
      $scope.listPref = [];
      $scope.checkItems = {}

      for (var j = 0; j < $scope.temp.Cargo.length; j++) {
        var result1 = $filter('filter')($scope.temp.Cargo, {
          CategoryTypeID: 1
        })[j];
        $scope.name = result1.ItemName;
        $scope.listPref.push($scope.name);

      }

      console.log($scope.listPref);
    }
```

and here is the json Data which i 'm getting:

```
{
  "Cargo": [{
    "ID": 1,
    "ItemName": "test",
    "CategoryTypeID": 1
  }, {
    "ID": 2,
    "ItemName": "test2",
    "CategoryTypeID": 1
  }, {
    "ID": 3,
    "ItemName": "test3",
    "CategoryTypeID": 1
  }]
}
```

[here is the image of my console window which shows me the object and array elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHCPH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Actually, you forgot **ng-model** there and the second problem is you used ng-repeat twice on your code. But there is no necessity of that.

```
<div id="btnid" class="list itemsDiv">
  <ion-list class="bg" ng-repeat="item in results">
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="item.ItemName"> 
      {{item.ItemName}}   
    </ion-checkbox>   
  </ion-list>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Updated my answer. Please go through once.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to force angular to update the UI using $scope.$apply function, this is caused by the using of promises and callbacks, check this article to a better comprehension.

[Article about Apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)